# Hover all element in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

Is there any way to add hover on all elements in html (div,p,span,a...) I'm trying like this:

```
$("*").hover(
      function () {
              $(this).addClass('hover'); ;
      },
      function () {
              $(this).removeClass('hover');
      }
    );
```

and CSS

```
#hover {
     background-color:#CC0000;
}
```

but somewhere there is an error???

Comment: Why do this with javascript?  Can't you just use the pseudo class `:hover` and do this entirely with CSS?  We'd need to see relevant HTML and which elements you want this on to advise more specifically.  It's rare to actually want all elements in the page (including body and all containers) to have the same behavior as that would likely look odd and probably not do what you want.

Comment: `*:hover { background-color: #CC0000; }` would be a lot simpler and more efficient.

Comment: I currenly build an app who will get xpath location from html code but now i want when user hover element to change background to know what element is select.

Comment: @JOJOJO Don't use the global selector then, just use it for the elements you want. Otherwise you `<body>`, and other unwanted elements will have it applied.

Comment: :) but i need this for all element (div,span,p,a)

Comment: Use the selector `div, span, p, a` and add the other ones you know you need. Using a blanket selector is generally not the way to go, since it could result in unintended side-effects.

Comment: $("div,span,p,a,li").hover ... ... is this the right way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using a `.` rather than a `#` to denote a class selector.

```
.hover {
    background-color:#CC0000;
}
```

Also, note that using `*` as a jQuery selector will select everything, including the body element etc. I'm not sure from the context of the question whether this is what you're after or not.

Furthermore, it would be easier to just use the CSS pseudo-class `:hover` to apply a style to a hovered element. Here's a reference for how to use it: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-hover

Comment: Yeah that will work. Just add any other elements in there with commas.

Answer (score 4):

You adding class "hover", but using CSS `#` selector for ids, use `.hover` instead of `#hover`

Answer (score 1):

jlis solution will work, but there is a better way:

Use the css pseudo class ":hover" instead:

```
*:hover {
     background-color: #CC0000;
}
```

should work with most common and actual browsers.

(IE 6 is **not** an actual or common browser!)

Comment: Uh yeah I agree, I had included that in my answer :P